# Consequences of getting "Declined Flags"

Tags: support, flagging

I guess the question 'how many 'decined flags' do a user get to make' is pointless, so, what are the consequences, if any, of getting too many?

How does the system calculates declined flags (*n* declined flags in *n* days/weeks/months?, or a ratio? or something else?) before the user sees the message:

> Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please
>   review them before flagging this post!

Comment: IMO, I don't think the numbers should be public. Whether it's a ratio or a just a threshold of declined flags. Making them public, would be just like telling wrongdoers "You can do this much damage/spam on this site".  Of course, keeping it private is not the solution for no spam, but it helps. *I'm not a strong supported of [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), I do think security holes should be fixed not hidden, but I do believe it helps in some cases when used correctly.*

Comment: @Dan yes I know making the numbers public can lead to problems, I am more concerned about the message and the consequences.

Comment: It's outlined here: Too many declined flags over a period of time will give you a warning, or a temporary ban, depending on how many were declined.