# Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!

Tags: support, flags

I get the "Attention: some of your recent flags have been declined - please review them before flagging this post!"  And I did review and yes, some of my SPAM flags were declined after which I flagged them for moderator attention with a bit more information and then they were sustained...

*So now that I have reviewed my flags, why am I still getting this?* <sub>(Yes, I know: there are also 3 declined NAA flags, but *I've reviewed them too!*)</sub>

Comment: Indeed. On a side note: I think that flags declined in first place but eventually accepted when raised as moderator flags *shouldn't* be counted as declined, but I really don't know if those, aside from namely reporting an incorrect information / annoying statement about your reviewing capacities actually count towards the inhibition of your flagging capabilities.

Comment: Yeah, I read the one on [meta.se] too!  That's why I'm asking...

Comment: In this case technically you still have also the 3 NaAs, however; I think that those eventually accepted count regardless, the system probably doesn't distinguish between "1 flag declined but then accepted" and "1 flag declined, 1 flag accepted" as it doesn't when giving the stats about the overall helpful / declined flags (which I agree it's wrong!).

Comment: Speaking just for the NaAs, I have no idea how one could be "safely" be stopped from being prompted by that message, since the system apparently can't have a clue about you having reviewed those flags or not other than by checking whether you loaded your flag history (is that reviewing?) or by trusting you :) I guess you'll be prompted until some kind of declined flags / time ratio goes under a certain threshold.

Comment: It's not preventing you from flagging, it will disappear soon enough. I don't think the exact time is documented however.. @kos, a few declined flags isn't a problem and the overhead of checking to see if this is a repeat flag would be extremely high.

Comment: @Seth Indeed, just expressing my dislike for the thing :) I'm sure there are legit (technical) reasons behind that choice

Comment: I posted a related question few days before: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14324/consequences-of-getting-declined-flags

Comment: @Ron: see answer below.  I suppose it answers both of our questions...  Shall you flag yours as duplicate of mine or shall I flag mine a duplicate of yours?  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: Since you've got an answer I think it's appropriate to mark mine as duplicate of yours even if I asked it first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So now that I have reviewed my flags, why am I still getting this?

The trigger of the message is simple: X% declined flags of the flags handled in the last Y days. It doesn't matter if you already reviewed the flags that were declined, the message will continue to appear until you get more helpful flags or the date the flags were declined pass.

Comment: So basically "doing nothing" will eventually remove this!  **:-)** Well, I'm *extremely good at doing nothing at all...*  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: ROFL, me too! :D