# How long will I be flag banned for?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

I'm flag banned at the moment (I had 4 declined in the last 7 days. That seems a little harsh, but that's not the topic of this discussion).

[image]

There is no indication of any way to get out of this ban, how long it will last for etc.

Is there anything I can do - and is there any time I can expect to be banned for?

Comment: Not an answer but I am n00b so I only flag stuff that absolutely appears to be what the flags are designed for. This means that some borderline stuff doesn't get flagged by me. On the good side, that means I have a 100% helpful rating with my flags. I don't *not* use them but I only use them sparingly and when I'm really sure they need flagging. But, as stated, I'm n00b.

Answer (score 2):

I nearly was [in the same situation](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14336/attention-some-of-your-recent-flags-have-been-declined-please-review-them-bef) as you, but when I got the warning, I just didn't flag anything for a couple of days and then it just went away...

So, forget about the review queues for a while, relax and let the other grunts handle it...  and next time when you get a warning: stop reviewing for a couple of days.

Comment: Not from reviews really... And the flag warning comes up at one wrong flag sometimes which bugs me. But yes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be unbanned tomorrow.  I *think* you can see that in the right column [here](https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-summary/186134).

Comment: I could be looking in the wrong place but i can't see it there, that just has the breakdown of type...