# Clarification about these two flags and the ban trigger

Tags: discussion

Apparently, I've been banned from flagging after I flagged these two non-answers + one answer:

- [This one](https://askubuntu.com/a/804425/271) talking entirely about Android Studio, while the question was about how to run the Android AVD Manager (different software) and Android Studio was only briefly mentioned by the OP in a previews review of the question
- [This one](https://askubuntu.com/a/547274/271) whose meaning basically reduces to *Please run `free` and post the output* which is clearly a "request for clarification" as mentioned in the standard not-an-answer comment, plus other "some patches not solutions" (citing the author **literally**)
- A third one which was admittedly an oversight of mine

I already checked [How long will I be flag banned for?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14581/how-long-will-i-be-flag-banned-for) which I think answers one of my concerns (assuming that this duration is the same for every user), however I still have some doubts:

- **How many** declined flags are required to trigger such a ban? Here I see 1 flag declined for a good reason and 2 which are honestly quite disputable
- Seriously, why was the first one declined? I can see how some people might decline a flag on a very low quality answer like the second one, but the first does *not* answer the question

Comment: I don't see any reason to flag the first one.

Comment: Same with the second. It is not a good answer IMO, but there is nothing to flag for.

Comment: Bad questions tend to produce bad answers, and users trying to do something with these answers tend to get declined flags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I declined your the first one.  First lets clear up one thing: Flags are not meant for "wrong" answers.  That is what downvotes and comments are for.  There is even a canned decline reason for wrong answers:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Obviously there are exceptions to this (that's what rules are for, right? Something I learned in English class), but in general if an answer is attempting to answer the question asked it should not be flagged for being wrong or missing parts of the question.  Use your downvotes and/or comments.

Now specifically for this post, the OP is obviously trying to open something related to the Android emulator.  The original question asks:

> and after completing step (6) [installing the packages] I **cannot open the android studio** to get to android device manager, I have looked everywhere for it and have **no idea where to find it or how to start it. Any Ideas?**

(emphasis added). The emulator was only mentioned in the title.  At this point we have a pretty bad, unclear question on our hands and almost any attempt to answer it will be akin to darts.  Someone is not going to hit the bullseye.  I declined the flag because, as best I could tell at the time, it was an attempt to answer the question and did not seem terribly far off the mark.

I did not process your flag on the other post so I cannot speak for that.  The best I can say is that besides asking for output of `free` it goes on to talk about adding swap and reinstalling.  How effective those things are going to be is unclear, but that's not what flags are for.

---

In regards to how flag bans are processed and handed out by the system, see [this meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405)

Comment: I would lift the ban because you took the time to try to understand, but there does not seem to be a button for that on my end..

Comment: Do you know how long the ban is? Bans for wrong reviewing (I got some) show the period.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The first one is not a "wrong" answer, it does not even attempt to answer the question. The OP asked "why can't I start *it*?" (*it* being the Android Studio first, then changed to Android AVD Manager) and the answer should have been **at least** "because [reason]" not "hey as far as I remember you either install Android Studio or the SDK". Besides, AFAIK there is also a "very low quality" flag and the review process can be used to suggest deletion of something because "it does not attempt to answer the question".